# Loop through the 1st row of HTML table (GridView) and get the cell content using Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, gridview, html-table, rows

I have a GridView which reads from a file and when I inspect element
its HTML table looks something like this :

```html
<div>
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <th id= "header1">...</th>
       <th id= "header2">...</th>
       <th id= "header3">...</th>
       <th id= "header4">...</th>
       <th id= "header5">...</th>
      <tr>..</tr>
      <tr>..</tr>
      <tr>..</tr>
      <tr>..</tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

I need to loop through the first row to be able to get the header values using javascript. I can't seem to loop through just the first row to extract values.

I understand that I  should count the number of columns first to create my "for" loop but I am only able to count my rows.

```
var table = document.getElementById("table1");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
```

There's nothing like table.columns.length.How do I do that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

like that you will get `header` values in an array

```js
const el = [...document.querySelectorAll("th")];

const res = el.map(el => el.innerHTML)

console.log(res)
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th id="header1">TEXT1</th>
        <th id="header2">TEX2</th>
        <th id="header3">TEXT3</th>
        <th id="header4">TEXT4</th>
        <th id="header5">TEXT5</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>..</tr>
      <tr>..</tr>
      <tr>..</tr>
      <tr>..</tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But what about looping? Is it possible to loop through  the 1st row in a table like above to get the values?

Comment: what do you mean by the first row ? loop on `<tr>` ?

Comment: yes, loop on the 1st <tr>.  I want to be able to visit every <th> within the first <tr> by using a for loop.